# Change colour of label in code - watchKit

Tags: swift, colors, watchkit, apple-watch

How can I change the colour of a label in watchKit using code? There are articles about doing it on iOS but this works differently in watchKit. I would like to do it in Swift.

Comment: Which color do you want to change? Background color or Text Color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use this Dylan Murphy:

```
label.setTextColor(UIColor.red)
```

You can change red to any default colour.